# wp-admin - spins for a while then blank page

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, wp-admin

ok - so i created a wordpress site for someone.
his hosting company just moved the site without telling anyone. some issues were created by this move.

now, a week or 2 later, i realise cant get into wp-admin. it spins on a white screen for a while then gives up.

just to eliminate the theme or plugins i've renamed both dirs but this didnt help.

the hosting guys have given me credentials for the mysql and ftp.

is there anything that would definitely need changing or updating following a server move to allow me access to wp-admin?

thanks,
nick

Comment: You get white screen on wp-admin right? Have you installed any security plugin?

Comment: Have you switched the theme to twenty eleven or is it working?

Comment: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-the-wordpress-white-screen-of-death/ , it might be helpfull

Comment: no security plugins.
ive changed to twenty eleven and it does the same thing
I've tried some of the things in that post already but i dont think its a problem with the installation - i think the issue is related to the fact that the site got moved to a different server.

Comment: Can you access the error logs?

Comment: Remove white space from functions.php code